# Delayed drawing of arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I want to draw an arrow which passes over another arrow in a tikz-cd commutative diagram. I can do that as follows from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=small]
  GM \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{M}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{M}}
     \arrow[swap]{dd}{Gf}
     \&      \& 
     R^{FM}
       \arrow{dd}{R^{Ff}} \\
     \& T M 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{M}}
    \arrow[swap,pos=0.75]{dd}{T f}
     \& \\
  GN \arrow[pos=0.75,crossing over]{rr}{\models_{N}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{N}}
     \&      \& R^{FN} \\
     \& T N 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{N}} \&    
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

However, I want the arrow `$Tf$` pass over the arrow `$\models_{N}$`. (I.e. the over and under crossing reversed). But as the arrow, which is supposed to be drawn over the other, is drawn before the other the `crossing over' option does not work.

I tried to use nodes for the entries in the diagram to be able to draw the arrow later (from node to node), but that gives me a compile error. I can always return to plain tikz, but I guess others using tikz-cd might find it also helpful to know how to use nodes or delay drawing an arrow. Any hint?

Comment: To name a node inside a tikz matrix, you can use |[alias=something]| at the beginning of the cell. For instance, replace line 12 with "\& |[alias=TM]| T M"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this?

[image: Result]

Although I must confess I don't have yet the general solution, for this particular case the effect was achieved by drawing the arrow from TN to TM instead of TM to TN. This way the arrow was drawn *after* the horizontal one. And of course I used `leftarrow` to get the arrowtip right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=small]
  GM \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{M}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{M}}
     \arrow[swap]{dd}{Gf}
     \&      \& 
     R^{FM}
       \arrow{dd}{R^{Ff}} \\
     \& T M 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{M}}
     \& \\
  GN \arrow[pos=0.75,crossing over]{rr}{\models_{N}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{N}}
     \&      \& R^{FN} \\
     \& T N 
    \arrow[leftarrow,pos=0.25,crossing over]{uu}{T f}  % <<----- HERE
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{N}} \&    
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

## Update: a more general solution

The above solution is *ad-hoc* and works only for this particular example. The general solution would allow to draw any additional arrow between two any nodes of the already typeset commutative diagram.

The idea is the following. Since internally `tikzcd` uses a `matrix of nodes` to typeset each node of the diagram, why wouldn't be possible to use those nodes as part of a path drawn after the diagram?

The idea is reasonable, but there are some issues here:

1. What are the names of each node in the diagram? Would it be possible to use the syntax `[(name)]` normally allowed inside a tikz `matrix of nodes`? Answer: no it is not possible, that would break the code of the `\arrow` macro, which relies in the auto-generated names for the nodes.
2. Then there are autogenerated names? Which are those names? Answer: They all begin with `\tikzmatrixname` and have the suffix `-row-column`. So for example, the first node of this diagram, (with label GM) would be `\tikzmatrixname-1-1`, the central node (TM) is `\tikzmatrixname-2-2`, and so on.
3. So it would be possible to add `\draw (\tikzmatrixname-1-1) to[bend left] (\tikzmatrixname-2-2)`; for example, after the matrix is done? i.e: this for example:

   ```
   \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=small]
     GM \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{M}}
     [...]
     \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{N}} \&
   % After all nodes are in the matris, draw some extra arrows
   \draw[bend left] (\tikzmatrixname-1-1) to[bend left] (\tikzmatrixname-2-2);
   \end{tikzcd}
   ```

   Answer: Sadly, the answer is no, this is not possible because of the way `tikcd` handles the diagram. Inside the `tikzcd` environment, surprisingly enought, no `tikz` commands can be issued. Indeed, all `tikz` commands are undefined, because the `tikzcd` environment *is not* a `tikzpicture` environment. This explains why you cannot use `\node`, `\draw` nor any other command.

   What `tikzcd` does is, each time you use the command `\arrow` or other equivalent,  to compute the appropiate `\path` command, but instead of "executing" it, it is stored in a list with all the other paths resulting from other `\arrow` commands. At the end of the `tikzcd` environment, a `tikzpicture` is created, which contains the `matrix of nodes`, and inside that picture, finally the list of `\path` commands is executed, drawing all the arrows.

So, what can we do?

It would be great if `tikzcd` provided a kind of `\drawAtTheEnd` command, which allows for storing any tikz drawing command in the same way that the list of paths, and execute that stored commands at the end of the `tikzcd` environment. This way we could add other arrows, decorations, define node coordinates with `overlay, remember picture` to be accessed from other parts of the page, etc.

In the meanwhile, I coded a hack which allows to insert a new path into the internal list used by tikzcd. The macro is called `\latearrow` and it takes four arguments:

1. The tikz options of the arrow (you can pass colours, `to path`s, `pos`,  etc
2. The name of the starting node, without the `\tikzmatrixnode` part. I.e: to refer to GM node you will call it `1-1`, the node TM will be `2-2`, and so on.
3. The name of the ending node (also without the `\tikzmatrixnode` part)
4. The text for the label in the arrow.

Using that macro, you can first draw your complete commutative diagram except for the arrow from TM to TN, and then add that arrow at the end with the syntax:

```
\latearrow{pos=0.75,crossing over}{2-2}{4-2}{T f}
```

As said, it is a quick&dirty hack, and does not use the same syntax than other arrows, does not allow for style options for the label, and I'm not sure if it would break anything, but apparently it works. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\makeatletter
\def\latearrow#1#2#3#4{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\tikzcd@savedpaths\path[/tikz/commutative diagrams/every arrow,#1]}%
  \global\edef\tikzcd@savedpaths{%
    \the\toks@%
    (\tikzmatrixname-#2)% \noexpand\tikzcd@sourceanchor)%
    to%
    node[/tikz/commutative diagrams/every label] {$#4$}
    (\tikzmatrixname-#3)% \noexpand\tikzcd@targetanchor)
;}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=small]
  GM \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{M}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{M}}
     \arrow[swap]{dd}{Gf}
     \&      \& 
     R^{FM}
       \arrow{dd}{R^{Ff}} \\
     \& T M 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{M}}
     \& \\
  GN \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{N}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{N}}
     \&      \& R^{FN} \\
     \& T N 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{N}} \&
\latearrow{pos=0.75,crossing over}{2-2}{4-2}{T f}
\latearrow{red, bend left}{1-1}{2-2}{x}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that I added a `blue` option to this arrow, to demonstrate that it works. Just for fun, I added also a red curved "late arrow" from GM to TM.
This is the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. I wonder, however, why the \node command gives me error messages. The shown example proved to be too simple, I need to see if my other cases can be done this way too. Thanks for this fix.

Comment: @BertfriedFauser I've updated my answer with a new hackish solution.

Comment: Regarding “`\drawAtEnd`”, isn't the key `execute at end picture` exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: It is indeed a bad idea to give a node a name, but you can give it an alias (see key `/tikz/alias`). Also, you can say `\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.style={name=<name>}]` to give the tikzcd matrix a specific name. (As you probably noticed, you can't use `\tikzmatrixname` in the to path parameter of an `\arrow`. The reason is that the argument to to path is only going to be expanded later, when the matrix has been finished and the value of `\tikztomatrix` forgotten. But you can certainly `\global\let\somethingelse=\tikzmatrixname` inside the `tikzcd` environment.)

Comment: @JLDiaz Thany oyu for the detailed explanation, that explains a lot, and most of the compile errors I got when trying stupid things. The \latearrow macro is great and will solve my other cases. I need to look at the other solutions, but that needs a few days.

Comment: @JLDiaz Thanks for this "latearrow" trick!  I used this just fine in something I wrote, but I recently updated to MacTeX 2015 and it stopped working.  Do you have any idea how I might fix it?  Specifically, if I leave the first argument empty it compiles alright, but if I put anything in there then it doesn't.

Answer (score 11):

The functionality of the top answer can be obtained directly using tikzcd by placing the following command at the end of the diagram:

```
\arrow[from=2-2, to=4-2, pos=0.75, crossing over, "T f"']
```

So the complete example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=small]
  GM \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{M}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{M}}
     \arrow[swap]{dd}{Gf}
     \&      \& 
     R^{FM}
       \arrow{dd}{R^{Ff}} \\
     \& T M 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{M}}
     \& \\
  GN \arrow[pos=0.75,crossing over]{rr}{\models_{N}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{N}}
     \&      \& R^{FN} \\
     \& T N 
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{N}} \&    
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=4-2, pos=0.75, crossing over, "T f"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### A solution by defining a command `\latearrow`

Similar to the solution given by JLDiaz, you can define a command `\latearrow`.
My version of `\latearrow` is set up so that tikzcd prints first the normal arrows in the order that they appear, then the `\latearrow`s in the order they appear. The syntax for `\latearrow` is exactly identical to the syntax of `\arrow`.

Note that this handles both the new and the old syntax correctly, so you can use the old syntax:

```
\latearrow[pos=0.75, crossing over,swap]{dd}{T f}
```

or the new syntax:

```
\latearrow[dd,pos=0.75, crossing over,"T f"']
```

and both work (making this work for the old syntax added 8 calls to `\patchcmd` and three `\let`'s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter

\patchcmd\tikzcd@
    {\global\let\tikzcd@savedpaths\pgfutil@empty}
    {\global\let\tikzcd@savedpaths\pgfutil@empty
    \global\let\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths\pgfutil@empty}{}{}

% For some reason this \patchcmd call fails =(
%\patchcmd\endtikzcd{\tikzcd@savedpaths}{\tikzcd@savedpaths\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths}{}{}

% So we have to copy the whole original version of \endtikzcd
\def\endtikzcd{%
  \pgfmatrixendrow\egroup%
  \pgfextra{\global\let\tikzcdmatrixname\tikzlastnode};%
  \tikzcdset{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-row diagram/.try}%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{% `quotes' library support
      /handlers/first char syntax/the character "/.initial=\tikzcd@forward@quotes,%
      /tikz/edge quotes mean={%
        edge node={node [execute at begin node=\iftikzcd@mathmode$\fi,%$
                         execute at end node=\iftikzcd@mathmode$\fi,%$
                         /tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every label,##2]{##1}}}}%
    \let\tikzcd@errmessage\errmessage% improve error messages
    \def\errmessage##1{\tikzcd@errmessage{##1^^J...^^Jl.\tikzcd@lineno\space%
        I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 
        \tikzcd@currentrow-\tikzcd@currentcolumn}}%
    \tikzcd@before@paths@hook%
    \tikzcd@savedpaths\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths % I just added \tikzcd@atendsavedpaths
  \endgroup%
  \endtikzpicture%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi}

\let\latearrow\tikzcd@arrow % \patchcmd comes through for us here.
\let\late@@arrow\tikzcd@@arrow
\let\late@ar@new\tikzcd@ar@new
\let\late@ar@old\tikzcd@ar@old
\let\late@ar@getlabel\tikzcd@ar@getlabel
\patchcmd\latearrow{\tikzcd@savedpaths}{\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths}{}{}
\patchcmd\latearrow{\tikzcd@@arrow}{\late@@arrow}{}{}
\patchcmd\latearrow{\tikzcd@ar@old}{\late@ar@old}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@@arrow{\tikzcd@ar@old}{\late@ar@old}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@@arrow{\tikzcd@ar@new}{\late@ar@new}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@old{\tikzcd@ar@getlabel}{\late@ar@getlabel}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@old{\tikzcd@ar@getlabel}{\late@ar@getlabel}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@old{\tikzcd@ar@new}{\late@ar@new}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@getlabel{\tikzcd@ar@getlabel}{\late@ar@getlabel}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@getlabel{\tikzcd@ar@getlabel}{\late@ar@getlabel}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@getlabel{\tikzcd@ar@new}{\late@ar@new}{}{}
\patchcmd\late@ar@new{\tikzcd@savedpaths}{\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths}{}{}
\def\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths{}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=small]
  GM \arrow[pos=0.75]{rr}{\models_{M}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{M}}
     \arrow[swap]{dd}{Gf}
     \&      \&
     R^{FM}
       \arrow{dd}{R^{Ff}} \\
     \& T M\latearrow[pos=0.75, crossing over,swap]{dd}{T f} 
            % Here's the \latearrow call. This arrow will go on top.
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{M}}
     \& \\
  GN \arrow[pos=0.75,crossing over]{rr}{\models_{N}}
     \arrow[two heads,swap]{dr}{e_{N}}
     \&      \& R^{FN} \\
     \& T N
    \arrow[tail,swap]{ru}{m_{N}} \&
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The code works by 1) changing `\end{tikzcd}` so that it puts both `\tikzcd@savedpaths` and `\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths` into the diagram and 2) copying the `\arrow` code but modifying it to store the paths in `\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths` in place of `\tikzcd@savedpaths`. Because at the end they are used in the order
`\tikzcd@savedpaths\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths`, all paths created using the normal `\arrow` command are printed first, and then the paths using `\latearrow`, each in the order they appear.

For some reason the `\patchcmd` call that should do step 1 fails, so I just copied the entire definition of `\endtikzcd` and added the one extra command I needed.

I do step 2 by copying all of the internal commands used in `\arrow` and then using a bunch of calls to `\patchcmd` to link them to each other, and to replace the savedpaths macro. Because `\arrow` has exceptionally complicated syntax, there are four internal commands, each needing up to three substitutions.

Obviously updates to tikzcd may to break this code, but it's very simple so it shouldn't be hard to fix.

Edit: The version I posted yesterday was broken, thanks Aaron Mazel for noticing. I mistakenly thought that the savedpaths was local, and would be emptied automatically when the scope closes at the end of the environment. Instead it's global, and emptied at the beginning of the next tikzcd environment. The fix was to add the line:

```
\patchcmd\tikzcd@
    {\global\let\tikzcd@savedpaths\pgfutil@empty}
    {\global\let\tikzcd@savedpaths\pgfutil@empty
    \global\let\tikzcd@atendsavedpaths\pgfutil@empty}{}{}
```

Comment: @HoodChatham thank you for your concern. The problem turned out to be outdated packages!! I will delete my comment now.

Answer (score 7):

One approach here would be to break the arrow passing under into two pieces.  Here are some ideas on how to do this:

One possibility is to use the fact that there is a matrix cell exactly at the point where you want one of the arrows to be broken:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[]
   & A \arrow{dd}   &   \\
     B \arrow[-]{r} & {} \arrow{r}{\phi} & C \\
   & D           & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use the TikZ's perpendicular coordinate system (see pgf manual, section 13.3.1).  In the example below, the arrow starting at B would land in D, but we modify the actual path drawn by saying `to path={-- (\tikztostart -| \tikztotarget)}` (the `to path` key is explained in section 14.14 of the pgf manual).  This changes the endpoint of the arrow to be the intersection of a horizontal line through \tikztostart (in this case, the node containing B) and a vertical line through \tikztotarget (in this case, the node containing D).  For the second piece of this arrow, we proceed similarly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{tikzcd}[]
  &
    A \arrow{dd}
      & \\
  B \arrow[-,
           shorten >=0.7ex,
           to path={-- (\tikztostart -| \tikztotarget)}]
          {rd}
    &
      &
        C \\
   &
     D \arrow[shorten <=0.7ex,
              to path={(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)
                         -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}]
             {ru}
             {\phi}
       &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Finally, a generalization of the above for possibly slanted or curved lines can be achieved using the `intersections` library (section 13.3.2 of the pgf manual).  I hope the example below will be self-explaining.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[name path=above]{rd}
    & B \arrow[name path=below, draw=none]{ld}
        \arrow[name intersections={of=above and below},
               -,
               shorten >=0.7ex,
               to path={-- (intersection-1)}]{}
        \arrow[shorten <=0.7ex,
               to path={(intersection-1) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}]
              {ld}{\phi}
    \\
  C
    & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the last one, as I have crossings which are not at matrix nodes.